# What does it refer to in the passage? Does it mean

Tags: meaning

Does ***it***(line12) mean 'people using the phonograph to communicate with friends and using the telephone to listen to music'?

> For some reason, sound technology seems to induce a strange sort of
> deafness among its most advanced pioneers. Some new tool comes along
> to share or transmit sound in a new way, and again and again its
> inventor has a hard time imagining how the tool will eventually be
> used. When Thomas Edison completed Édouard-Léon Scott de Martinville’s
> original project and invented the phonograph in 1877, he imagined it
> would regularly be used as a means of sending audio letters through
> the postal system. Individuals would record their missives on the
> phonograph’s wax scrolls, and then pop them into the mail, to be
> played back days later. Bell, in inventing the telephone, made what
> was effectively a mirror-image miscalculation: He envisioned one of
> the primary uses for the telephone to be as a medium for sharing live
> music. An orchestra or singer would sit on one end of the line, and
> listeners would sit back and enjoy the sound through the telephone
> speaker on the other. So, the two legendary inventors had ***it***
> exactly reversed: people ended up using the phonograph to listen to
> music and using the telephone to communicate with friends.

[How We Got to Now: Six Innovations that Made the Modern World
By Steven Johnson](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=T8KzBAAAQBAJ&pg=PP71&lpg=PP71&dq=So,%20the%20two%20legendary%20inventors%20had%20it%20exactly%20reversed:%20people%20ended%20up%20using%20the%20phonograph%20to%20listen%20to%20music%20and%20using%20the%20telephone%20to%20communicate%20with%20friends.&source=bl&ots=Xew7JubapE&sig=ACfU3U2p1ov18d4nwyhBJDkl8HRFv9c1Pw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi2hKCfnJjvAhXQaN4KHSn6DPQQ6AEwAXoECAQQAw#v=onepage&q=So,%20the%20two%20legendary%20inventors%20had%20it%20exactly%20reversed:%20people%20ended%20up%20using%20the%20phonograph%20to%20listen%20to%20music%20and%20using%20the%20telephone%20to%20communicate%20with%20friends.&f=false)

Comment: **It** = what they expected the situation would be.

Answer (score 1):

It does, yes.

We might argue that a little licence is taken in pooling their incorrect predictions and supposing that they both believed both, which was most likely not the case.

It really means that hypothetically combined/together they had it reversed.